# How to loop images sequence?

Tags: python, image, loops

I want to continusly loop image gallery (folder) until I press a key.
So I have a folder with 3 images 1,2,3. I want to display them in order and then to repeat.

I've used while but I didn't manage to make it work.

```
import Image

image1 = Image.open('image1.jpg')
image.show()
image2 = Image.open('image2.jpg')
image.show()
image3 = Image.open('image3.jpg')
image.show()
```

Comment: use glob module: https://pymotw.com/2/glob/

Answer (score 0):

See if this works. I'm sure there is an easier way, but this is what I could think of.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, abspath
import time
import subprocess

mypath = abspath(__file__)
files_in_folder = [f for f in listdir() if isfile(join(mypath, f))]

# get images
imgs = []
for f in files_in_folder:
    _, file_extension = os.path.splitext(f)
    if file_extension = ".jpg"
    imgs.append(f)

# run loop until keyboard interrupt
try:
    while True:
        for img in imgs:
            viewer = subprocess.Popen(['some_viewer', img])
            viewer.terminate()
            time.sleep(3)
            viewer.kill()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you. Do i need to add the folder path?

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand, where do I place my path?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use the `glob` module:

```
import Image
from glob import glob

path = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Folder'
#images = []

for ing in glob(path+'\\*.jpg'):
    image = Image.open('image1.jpg')
    #images.append(image)
    image.show()
```

The commented lines of code are for if you want to be able to access the images later in the code.